# Аннотация полей в Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть несколько моделей:

```py
class Report(Model):
    projects = ManyToManyField('Project', through='ProjectState')

class Project(Model):
    cost = IntegerFielf()

class ProjectState(Model):
    project = ForeignKey('Project')
    report = ForeignKey('Report')
```

Мне нужно получить список `Report` с аннотированным полем `avg_cost`, которым является среднее `Project.cost` для каждого `report`.

Что-то подобное, только работоспособное:

```py
Report.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    avg_cost=Avg(
        Project.objects.values('id', 'cost').filter(
            id__in=OutRef('projects__id')
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Report.objects.filter(...).annotate(
  avg_cost=Avg('projects__cost')
}
```

Как то так.  Если не сработает, перед `annotate` вставьте `prefetch_related`, указав поле или через Prefetch  объект, если нужно доп сложная фильтрация

```
<queryset>.prefetch_related('projects').annotate(...)

# Или

<queryset>.prefetch_related(
  Prefetch('projects',  Project.objects.filter(....))
).annotate(...)
```

Comment: О, ваше решение, похоже работает. Но у меня есть ещё одно обстоятельство, которое вызывает ошибку (я о нём не указал, так как не предполагал, что оно приведёт к ошибке). Оно в том, что сама модель `Project` не имеет поля `cost`, оно аннотируется в другом подзапросе, и поэтому код `report_queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('projects__cost', queryset=projects_with_cost)).annotate(avg_cost=Avg('projects__cost'))` выдаёт ошибку `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'cost' into field. ` (что у проектов нет поля `cost`). При этом `report_queryset[0].projects.all()[0].cost` работает нормально.

Comment: Ну тогда через `Prefetch`, как вы написали, но `projects`

Comment: `report_queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('projects', queryset=projects_with_cost)).annotate(avg_cost=Avg('projects__cost'))` - та же ошибка.

Comment: `projects_with_cost`  что у вас там? покажите как собираете `queryset`

Comment: `projects_with_cost = Project.objects.annotate( cost=Subquery( Settings.objects.filter(date__lte=models.OuterRef('date_created')).latest('-date').values('value') ) )`. На выходе поле `cost` имеет тип `Decimal`.

Без аннотации `avg_cost` код `report_queryset[0].projects.all()[0].cost` ожидаемо выдаёт `Decimal('550.000000000000')`.

Comment: Хм, странно. С `Subquery`  я не работал, так что не подскажу что тут не так. Последний вариант должен был сработать

Comment: Также если я делаю `report_queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('projects', queryset=projects_with_cost, to_attr='qwerty'))`, то у объектов `(report := reports[0])` появляется поле `qwerty`, но `Avg('qwerty')` его не видит.

Comment: Тут, видимо, как-то по-особенному для джанги надо прописывать аннотированные поля для агрегаций. Но спасибо всё равно, так как исходная проблема решена, это уже другая. Как найду решение - в комменты кину, чтобы вы тоже посмотрели :)

Comment: Оказалось, что `prefetch` не нужен, тк он вызывается уже после аннотаций. Нужно было просто сделать две аннотации подряд, сначала аннотацию для `projects__cost`, а следом на её основе для `avg_cost`.